# CodeSmith generator not generating classes

Tags: codesmith

We use CodeSmith and Nhibernate 3.2 for generating our BusinessObjects and Viewmodels. 
My codesmith templates were working fine till last week. Not sure what I did specifically but suddenly my viewmodels stopped generating. Business objects are working correctly.
There are no errors. It says all the templates are built successfully and class.generated.cs has been generated. But there is nothing added

I get the following in the output window which basically says that it was successful.  My business objects on the other hand are rendering correctly. It is only the viewmodels. I checked the connection string and got latest to make sure I have the correct template files. 
I am running visual studio as an administrator. Could it be a permissions issue.. ? Can someone help please!!..What are the dependencies for codesmith Even if I were to compare why Business Objects are working and not viewmodels, where would I need to start. I can post some necessary code in the template if needed.

```
Generating project "C:\ViewModels.csp" outputs...
Compiling template "C:\NHibernateViewModels.cst"...
Template compilation succeeded. (97 ms)
Rendering output 'Project.ViewModels'...
  Generated: C:MyViewModel.generated.cs
Done rendering outputs: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped (90375ms).
```

Answer (score 0):

I work for CodeSmith Tools, It could be that you are not generating updated hbm mapping files, it looks like your csp file is only rendering out the view models.

Comment: @Blakd Niemyjski, Hello thanks for looking at it.. I checked hbm mapping and looks like it updated mapping files.. I am thinking it a permission thing.. We have  an older version of the application and it works correctly there. Its the same template

Comment: Please let me know what you find.